# Rails 4 Dragonfly Gem with Amazon S3 Direct Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dragonfly-gem

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate S3 with dragonfly. This gem works locally, but because I'm using Heroku, the files gets deleted... so, I'm thinking I need to implement it into S3.

I'm using this gem: [dragonfly-s3_data_store](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly-s3_data_store) where my dragonfly.rb looks like this:

**/config/initializers/dragonfly.rb**

```
require 'dragonfly'
require 'dragonfly/s3_data_store'

# Configure
Dragonfly.app.configure do
  plugin :imagemagick

  url_format "/media/:job/:name"

  datastore :s3,
    bucket_name: 'thelab',
    access_key_id: '{my access key}',
    secret_access_key: '{my secret key}',
    region: "us-west-1"
end

... #more code
```

This is my error when I'm trying to upload an image:

```
hostname "thelab.thelab.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I'm not sure what's causing the issue, but also on my console, I see this popping up:

```
[fog][WARNING] fog: followed redirect to thelab.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com, connecting to the matching region will be more performant
```

There's inconsistency here... I've also tried to switch the region to us-west-2, but I still get the same errors and warning signs.

form:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f|
  = f.file_field :image
  = f.button :submit, "Save changes"
```

And of course, the model, in this case user.rb, has this:

```
dragonfly_accessor :image
```

Am I missing anything else that needs to be configured?

Also, my CORS Configuration for thelab bucket

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: have you tried removing `url_format "/media/:job/:name"`?